# Simple PHP Password Page - Why Encrypt?

Tags: php, forms, passwords

Let's say you have a simple page that requires a password, you email this page to a friend with the password, so that they can view hidden information within.

Is this insecure and why?

```
$password = htmlentities($_POST["password"]);
echo ($password == "hello123" && strlen($password) <= 10)
? "secret information" : "incorrect password";
```

What possible attack could someone pull off? I image they would try to break out of the query? How is encrypting the password within the page (SHA1) anymore secure?

Comment: Hashed -- *not* encrypted -- passwords are standard procedure to prevent exposing user passwords *if* the database containing the password gets compromised.  If you don't care about that password getting exposed if your code gets exposed, then you're fine.  Given that your server would be compromised in that situation, you're pretty screwed regardless...

Comment: for something so simple, Apache authentication is ideal

Comment: So let me get this straight. Even if you decided to store the password in a mySQL database, you would have to hack into the server and decrypt.

Comment: a hashed password offers a degree of protection from bruit force by making each attempt slower, its real benefit is if the server is compromised and the attacker has the whole db

Comment: okay that seems about right, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashing a password is a must, if users choose their own passwords. Often they reuse the same password for several sites and if your site leakes, other more important sites are compromised as well.

Even if you place the password hardcoded in the code, it is better to just place a hash of it into the code. There is minimal work to do and everybody with access to the server can read the password otherwise (hoster, lost backups, version-control, ...).

Getting a password from a database is usually easier (SQL-injection) than getting a hardcoded password from the code (needs privileges on the server), so passwords in the database need to be better protected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no query. For a simple page like this, there's no reason to secure it further, because a hacker would have to access your server's filesystem to find the password.

Answer (score 0):

a simple hash (like sha1) can be attacked with > 1 billion tries per second by 15y old attackers with a clue and a gamer gfx card (if the attacker gets the hash and tries to find the cleartext password, e.g. after finding some way to read the hash from whereever you store it).

this is even still true if you add a salt to the hash.

so, don't write your own password code if you don't need to, there are lots of ways to have proven code check some password for you (e.g. by some apache module, maybe by a good php password library, ...).

an indication that the password code is maybe ok and modern enough is when it uses stuff like pbkdf2, bcrypt, scrypt, sha512-crypt internally.